# SFTP Progress with SSH.NET

Tags: vb.net, ssh, sftp, progress

VB2010 with [SSH.NET](https://sshnet.codeplex.com/).

I've downloaded and implemented the library to do an SFTP download and it works great. I've been looking at the documentation and examples and just cannot see how to implement an SFTP download with progress. I want to display the progress of the download as it occurs. So far I have:

```
Imports Renci.SshNet
Imports System.IO

    Using sftp As New SftpClient("0.0.0.0", 25, "id", "pwd")
        'connect to the server
        sftp.Connect()

        'the name of the remote file we want to transfer to the PC
        Dim remoteFileName As String = "/data/OUT/trips.txt"

        'download the file as a memory stream and convert to a file stream
        Using ms As New MemoryStream
            'download as memory stream
            sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, ms)

            'create a file stream
            Dim fs As New FileStream("c:\mytrips.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

            'write the memory stream to the file stream
            ms.WriteTo(fs)

            'close file stream
            fs.Close()

            'close memory stream
            ms.Close()
        End Using

        'disconnect from the server
        sftp.Disconnect()

        MsgBox("The file has been downloaded from the server.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Using
```

Edit: ok I've done some research and found an example in the codeplex discussion forum. Out of that I learned that there is another downloading function which is asynchronous which I will use. Its a good approach to displaying progress in the debug window and also a progressbar control. Feel free to comment.

```
Imports Renci.SshNet
Imports System.IO
Imports Renci.SshNet.Sftp
Dim fileSize As Long

Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Try
        Using sftp As New SftpClient("0.0.0.0", 25, "id", "pwd") 
            'connect to the server
            sftp.Connect()

            'the name of the remote file we want to transfer to the PC
            Dim remoteFileName As String = "/Data/OUT/Config.txt"

            'check for existence of the file
            Dim IsExists As Boolean = sftp.Exists(remoteFileName)
            If IsExists Then
                'get the attributes of the file (namely the size)
                Dim att As Sftp.SftpFileAttributes = sftp.GetAttributes(remoteFileName)
                fileSize = att.Size

                'download the file as a memory stream and convert to a file stream
                Using ms As New MemoryStream
                    'download as memory stream
                    'sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, ms, AddressOf DownloadCallback) 'with download progress
                    'sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, ms) 'without download progress

                    'here we try an asynchronous operation and wait for it to complete.
                    Dim asyncr As IAsyncResult = sftp.BeginDownloadFile(remoteFileName, ms)
                    Dim sftpAsyncr As SftpDownloadAsyncResult = CType(asyncr, SftpDownloadAsyncResult)
                    While Not sftpAsyncr.IsCompleted
                        Dim pct As Integer = CInt((sftpAsyncr.DownloadedBytes / fileSize) * 100)
                        Debug.Print("Downloaded {0} of {1} ({2}%).", sftpAsyncr.DownloadedBytes, fileSize, pct)
                        pgbMain.Value = pct

                        Application.DoEvents()
                    End While
                    sftp.EndDownloadFile(asyncr)

                    'create a file stream
                    Dim localFileName As String = "c:\" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM_HHmmss") & "_test.txt"
                    Dim fs As New FileStream(localFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

                    'write the memory stream to the file stream
                    ms.WriteTo(fs)

                    'close file stream
                    fs.Close()

                    'close memory stream
                    ms.Close()
                End Using

                'disconnect from the server
                sftp.Disconnect()

                'success
                MsgBox("The file has been downloaded from the server.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                MsgBox("The file does not exist on the server.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Finally
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Try
End Sub
```

My test file took 0.4 seconds to download so it was hard to see the progress. Larger files test really well.

Comment: Are you looking for a progress bar, or to do SFTP with the Progress client?

Comment: What I would like is a progress report so that I can update a progress bar or a label with the status.

Comment: It's odd because the codeplex site says "Provide status report for upload and download sftp operations to allow accurate progress bar implementation" but cant really find how this is implemented.

Comment: There is a Downloading() event on the client - that is where I would look for progress. Downloaded help (.chm file) doesn't seem to work so there doesn't appear to be any usable documentation. Right click the ssfnet client object and goto definition. The event args has Size and Downloaded.

Comment: OK i see it but thats for the ScpClient class. Im using the SftpClient class. Although I see now that the SftpClient.DownloadFile has an option for a callback. So i could do sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, ms, AddressOf DownloadCallback). Sort of works. Maybe my file is too small to display in a progress.

Comment: I edited my op with research, findings, and a solution. My last step is to test with large files as the file I used was small and the download was almost instantaneous so couldn't really see the progress in the progressbar.

Comment: @sinDizzy so is your progress bar working?

Comment: This was a long time ago but yes it is working.

Comment: @sinDizzy I suppose you don't have anything about this right now but I should try. Did you develop something to cancel the process with a button, just in case you need to do it?

Comment: No cancellation but am sure you can use the above sample and tweak it for your needs.

Comment: Yes, I did it already using boolean variables and checking if its status changes when a user clicks the cancel button. I'd like to make it using SSH.NET resources but it seems the package doesn't have something similar.

Comment: @sinDizzy Why don't you post an answer to your question and close this question. It's been there for months with no answers but lot a views because it's unanswered but answered.... please fix it.

Comment: The answer was in my edit. What is the proper way to answer my own question and then close it?

Comment: @sinDizzy : Just write an answer below and accept it. This is known as a _self-answered question_, which is okay (and a somewhat common thing to do), if that was what you were unsure of. :)

Comment: @sinDizzy As already mentioned above, please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done some research and found an example in the codeplex discussion forum. Out of that I learned that there is another downloading function which is asynchronous which I will use. Its a good approach to displaying progress in the debug window and also a progressbar control. Feel free to comment

```
    Imports Renci.SshNet
    Imports System.IO
    Imports Renci.SshNet.Sftp
    Dim fileSize As Long

    Private Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Try
        Using sftp As New SftpClient("0.0.0.0", 25, "id", "pwd") 
            'connect to the server
            sftp.Connect()

            'the name of the remote file we want to transfer to the PC
            Dim remoteFileName As String = "/Data/OUT/Config.txt"

            'check for existence of the file
            Dim IsExists As Boolean = sftp.Exists(remoteFileName)
            If IsExists Then
                'get the attributes of the file (namely the size)
                Dim att As Sftp.SftpFileAttributes = sftp.GetAttributes(remoteFileName)
                fileSize = att.Size

                'download the file as a memory stream and convert to a file stream
                Using ms As New MemoryStream
                    'download as memory stream
                    'sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, ms, AddressOf DownloadCallback) 'with download progress
                    'sftp.DownloadFile(remoteFileName, ms) 'without download progress

                    'here we try an asynchronous operation and wait for it to complete.
                    Dim asyncr As IAsyncResult = sftp.BeginDownloadFile(remoteFileName, ms)
                    Dim sftpAsyncr As SftpDownloadAsyncResult = CType(asyncr, SftpDownloadAsyncResult)
                    While Not sftpAsyncr.IsCompleted
                        Dim pct As Integer = CInt((sftpAsyncr.DownloadedBytes / fileSize) * 100)
                        Debug.Print("Downloaded {0} of {1} ({2}%).", sftpAsyncr.DownloadedBytes, fileSize, pct)
                        pgbMain.Value = pct

                        Application.DoEvents()
                    End While
                    sftp.EndDownloadFile(asyncr)

                    'create a file stream
                    Dim localFileName As String = "c:\" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM_HHmmss") & "_test.txt"
                    Dim fs As New FileStream(localFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)

                    'write the memory stream to the file stream
                    ms.WriteTo(fs)

                    'close file stream
                    fs.Close()

                    'close memory stream
                    ms.Close()
                End Using

                'disconnect from the server
                sftp.Disconnect()

                'success
                MsgBox("The file has been downloaded from the server.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Else
                MsgBox("The file does not exist on the server.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    Finally
        Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    End Try
End Sub
```